# properties of sub-gaussian random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$Given the tail property of sub-gaussian random variable $\exists c>0, \forall \lambda >0, P(|X|\ge\lambda)\le2e^{-c\lambda^2}$, prove that $\exists a>0, \E e^{aX^2}\le2$. Although I have the result but I am getting two different expression using different approach.

Approach 1. Using $\E[g(x)] = g(a) +\int_a^\infty g'(x)(1-F_X(x)) \,dx $ if $P(X\ge a)=1$ [source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition]

$$Ee^{aX^2} = 1 + \int_0^\infty 2ate^{at^2}P(|X|>t)\,dt \le 1+\int_0^\infty 2at\cdot e^{at^2}\cdot2e^{-ct^2}dt=1+\frac{2a}{c-a}$$

Approach2. Let $Y=e^{aX^2}$
$$P(Y\ge y)=P(e^{aX^2}\ge y)=P\left(X^2\ge\frac 1 a \ln y\right) = P \left(|X|\ge\sqrt{\frac 1 a \ln y} \,\,  \right) \le 2e^{\frac{-c}a \ln y}$$

Now using the fact that for positive random variable $\E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P(Y\ge y) \,dy$, we have

$$Ee^{aX^2}\le \int_1^\infty 2e^{\frac{-c}a \ln y} = \frac{2a}{c-a}$$

Not able to figure out the error?

Comment: The result you were asked to show is slightly surprising: if $P(|X|\geqslant x)=e^{-cx^2}$ for every $x>0$ then the hypothesis holds but, for every $a<c$, $$E(e^{aX^2})=\int_0^\infty e^{ax^2}2cxe^{-cx^2}dx=\frac{c}{c-a}$$ which goes to infinity when $a\to c$, so how could one show that $E(e^{aX^2})\leqslant2$ for every $0<a<c$? Relatedly, I am curious to see how you turned the indications in Dominik's answer (which you instantly accepted) into a full solution.

Comment: @Did Sorry about this. But the problem was to show that there exist a>0 such that the results holds. In that case  we can choose a to be c/3 in the solution above. Also I think there is a typo in your expression, shouldn't it be $\frac{a}{c-a}$. Thanks

Comment: If this was indeed your problem then you were right to modify your question but then, much more synthetic arguments than yours allow to prove the desired result. (No typo in my previous comment, thanks, try $a=0$ to get an idea of why $c/(c-a)$ is correct.)

Comment: @Did Yeah you are right. Just curious though how did you arrive at your expression. On side note I was reading a proof of deriving sub-guassian mgf property $\exists b, \forall t, Ee^{tX} <= e^{\frac{t^2b^2}{2}}$ given the above result and they start with the following expression $Ee^{tX}=1+\int_0^1 (1-y)E[(tX)^2e^{ytX}]dy$ which I am not able to figure out. Can you please give some hint on this. Thanks

Comment: Re "my" expression, simply note that $$e^{ax^2}2cxe^{-cx^2}=\frac{c}{c-a}2(c-a)xe^{-(c-a)x^2}=-\frac{c}{c-a}\left(e^{-(c-a)x^2}\right)'$$ Re the formula in your last comment, if I had to prove it, I would try to show the pointwise identity $$e^z=1+z^2\int_0^1(1-y)e^{yz}dy$$ for every nonnegative $z$, and apply it to $z=tX(\omega)$, then integrate the result with respect to $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P(Y > y) = 1$ for $0 \le y \le 1$, so you can't just skip the integral from $0$ to $1$. Then you get the same result.